# Is Aemon Targaryen the only named character in Westeros who died of old age?

Tags: game-of-thrones, a-song-of-ice-and-fire

I was browsing, when I saw this image:

[image: "Aemon Targaryen, the only person to die of old age in Game of Thrones" meme]

How accurate is this statement? I know that in the TV Show, Aemon was the first main character who died of old age, but are there other characters (less important, or before the war of five kings) who died of old age?

Comment: Too lazy to look through everyone especially from the books and lore. But the obvious one to me is Hoster Tully.

Comment: @Gallifreyan by ruler i mean important character who have power. Aemon was a maester, so he didn't hold any lands, but he was an important character.

Comment: It will become an open-ended list question. I'd suggest that you should either remove the books tag (As there are ALOT of such characters in the books) or you should mention a timeline i.e. from 230 AC to 300 AC and social class i.e. The character must be a landed noble and/or a culture group i.e. the character must be Riverlander to reduce the scope.

Comment: This is difficult to answer, in that "old age" is not really something you die of. You die of complications of illnesses that you become more susceptible to as you age. So for example, whether Hoster Tully dying of stomach cancer (most likely) at around 60 counts as "dying of old age" is a matter of debate.

Answer (score 50, accepted):

### No he is not

Put bluntly, no. There is one other Major player in the time of the War of the Five Kings who dies of Natural causes, Hoster Tully. But here's a list of people that have dies of old age in a Song of Ice and Fire and a Game of Thrones.

## Game of Thrones

I got my information for this from [this site](https://deathtimeline.com/) all the credit goes to them. They did a great job chronicling all onscreen deaths and according to them other than Aemon Targaryen, the only death of old age or due to natural causes was Hoster Tully.

- #### [Hoster Tully,](http://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/Hoster_Tully)

  aged between 58-61, died of old age in the company of his daughter Catelyn and grandson Robb.

## A Song of Ice and Fire

### People who died of Natural causes, i.e. illnesses etc. Possibly due to old age.

All those who died in the TV show (just Hoster Tully, lol) and:

- #### [Harlan Grandison,](http://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/Harlan_Grandison)

  of unknown age, but died in his sleep, whose death allowed Jaime to join the Kingsguard.
- #### [Meria Martell,](http://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/Meria_Martell)

  probably died of old age and sickness in 13AC, fat, blind, and almost bald. She was ruler of Dorne during Aegon Conquest and First Dornish War
- #### [Aegon I Targaryen,](http://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/Aegon_I_Targaryen)

  Died aged 67 on Dragonstone of a stroke. Likely caused due to his waining health in old age.
- #### [Jaehaerys I Targaryen,](http://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/Jaehaerys_I_Targaryen)

  Longest reigning Targaryen monarch, sitting on the throne for fifty-five years, he died in 103AC at the age of sixty-nine
- #### [Viserys I Targaryen,](http://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/Viserys_I_Targaryen)

  Although only 52 at his death, Viserys died in his sleep with no other complications given. Although not necessarily old (compared to Maestor Aemon) no illness or other complications are given as a cause of death.
- #### [Jaehaerys II Targaryen,](http://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/Jaehaerys_II_Targaryen)

  a mere 37, whose death caused the ascension of Aerys II to the throne, which would eventually be his demise.
- #### [Ser Arlan of Pennytree,](http://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/Arlan_of_Pennytree)

  aged around 56-60, possibly counts as of "old age", died of a chill, Knight and tutor to former Lord Commander of the Kingsguard, Ser Duncan the Tall.
- #### [Daeron the Good,](http://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/Daeron_II_Targaryen)

  aged 56 at his time of death, and his grandsons Valarr and Matarys along with the High Septon and several other notables during the Great Spring Sickness of 210AC.
- #### [Lady Tanda Stokeworth](http://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/Tanda_Stokeworth)

  of unknown age, likely ripe and old, died of a chill in 300AC.
- #### [Lord Gyles Rosby](http://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/Gyles_Rosby)

  of unknown age, likely ripe and old, died of sickness in 300AC.

Comment: Other people who died old men out of natural causes would be Aegon I, Jaehaerys I, Viserys I, Viserys II, Aegon IV off the top of my head.

Comment: Actually Viserys II is a bit if-fy. There were rumors that Aegon IV poisoned him but nothing was ever proven so yeah

Comment: Yes, but all those others were really, really minor characters. Did any get any screen time or speaking roles in the TV show? Going by just recurring characters on the TV show, Aemon might be the only one.

Comment: Hoster Tully says something in the show, maybe just a gargle

Comment: @LincolnMan The OP has used the books tag as well. Edlothiad is answering from the books, not the show as most of these characters aren't even mentioned in the show

Comment: @Aegon I might start cutting down this answer based on screen time in the TV series as suggested by LincolnMan

Comment: Hoster Tully died of a long illness, not old age, at least in the books. I'm not sure if the TV series ever actually tells us how he died.

Comment: These answers depend on your definition of "death by old age." In modern times, we say old people who die of cancer to have "died of cancer" not of "old age." However, it's implied that if that person were younger, they would have been significantly less likely to get cancer in the first place. Hoster Tully "died of an illness" that he got in his old age - shouldn't we say that the illness took him, not his old age?

Comment: How the heck do you die of old age at 37? *Kids these days ...*

Comment: @Randal'Thor put your reading glasses on, it says "*possibly* of old age"

Comment: If I remember correctly, Tytos Lannister died of natural causes, something like a heart attack.

Comment: But the question is specifically about people who died of old age, not of "illnesses etc."

Comment: @Randal'Thor no one dies of "old age" itself. People who die of 'illnesses etc.' which are more prevalent in older people are said to die of old age. Someone dying of 'a chill' will have to be already weak and infirm.

Comment: @PeteKirkham Sure, dying of old age often means dying of illness, but not everyone dying of illness is dying of old age.

Comment: @Randal'Thor Hence why there's a *possibility*, also who knows the life expectancy of westeros with all the deaths I'd say it could easily be in the 40s

Answer (score 11):

As mentioned in the comments, [Hoster Tully](http://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/Hoster_Tully), Lord Paramount of the Trident and Lord of Riverrun died in his bed, around 60 years old

Another ruler who die of old age is [Meria Martell](http://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/Meria_Martell), who died after ruling Dorne for more than seventy years, and won the First Dornish War

Comment: You should add characters to your own answer instead of adding them to Edlothiad's. It's not a Community Wiki.

Comment: @Aegon I just don't see the point to have two different list, while it would be better to have one, complete list

Comment: well that's for Edlothiad to decide or for the Mods to decide. Right now you would be better off compiling your own answer. Each answer is judged on its own merit. You can request Edlothiad to make it a CW, he was thinking about that earlier. Then you can both collaborate on it and you wont need to go through edit review process